# Pandas reading large panel CSV efficiently in chunks based on values of a column

Tags: python, pandas, bigdata

I have a large CSV file (~50 GB on disk), and am unable to read this entirely into memory at once. The dataset itself is panel data and looks something like

```
ID Time     Col 1 ... Col N
1  2000/1/1 ...
1  2000/1/2
...
2  2000/1/1 ...
...
```

My idea to load this data is to read it in chunks, do some pre-processing to reduce size, and then save each chunk individually. I am aware of using `pd.read_csv(..., chunksize=1000)` which lets me loop over chunks of size 1000, but for the pre-processing to be accurate, I would prefer to loop over chunks corresponding to the ID columns. (All the rows corresponding to a specific `ID` are required for accurate pre-processing)

In other words, let's say I have a smaller file that contains all the `ID` values (say, 1-1000). Then, I want to do something like

```
list_of_id_chunks = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], ... ] # Split the total IDs into chunks of 3 IDs each

for chunk_of_ids in list_of_id_chunks:
    # 1. Read the large csv file with only the rows where `ID` is in chunk_of_ids
    # (For the first iteration, this should have rows with ID = 1, 2, or 3)
    # 2. Do some preprocessing to trim file size
    # 3. Save files in csv, feather, etc
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: based on your question, the argument ```chunksize=1000``` does not work because the amount of rows for every ID-group are different? Is there a pattern/logic to the amount of amount of rows per ID-group?

Comment: Are the IDs are already ordered in the input? Is the reason `chunksize` is inadequate for your needs because the number of rows per ID is variable, or because the rows aren't contiguous?

Comment: Filtering chunks by ID isn't in stock. You could, however, read the CSVs row by row to get a series. Then you could save them with `to_csv` *with appending* then re-reading the appropriate data by ID.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could start with something like this, it reads your file 1 million lines at a time, breaks each chunk up by ID, and saves by ID to new files. In the end, you'd have a separate file for each ID.

```
with pd.read_csv('big_file.csv', chunksize=1e6) as reader:
    for chunk in reader:
        for name, group in chunk.groupby('ID'):
            group.to_csv(f'big_file_id_{name}.csv', mode='a', index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: This is along the lines of what I was thinking, but problem is that it doesn't guarantee that each chunk contains all the rows for each `ID` which can vary. So let's say the 0.9M - 1M rows are for ID `100`, but rows 1M-1.1M are also for ID `100`. This would replace the previous csv and also make preprocessing in the loop not accurate.

Comment: No... `mode='a'` means that it's *appending* to the file if it exists, so you can end up adding to the same ID's file multiple times, it doesn't matter where in the file anything is.

Comment: Actually I just noticed the `mode='a'` will take care of that along with `header=not os.path.exists(...)`. After saving, I'll then loop again and do the preprocessing. Thanks!

Comment: Ye, you can make it more robust adding headers with a check if the file exists already or not~

Answer (score 0):

If you know the indices of the chunk edges (in your example the edges would be `[0, 4, 7, 10]`) then you can make use of skiprows and nrows in pandas read_csv to achieve this

here is a sample snippet - hope it helps

```py
In [18]: df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]})

In [19]: df.to_csv("test.csv", index=None)

In [20]: indices_to_split = [0, 4, 7, 10] # these are the edges of your ids
    ...: 
    ...: for idx, (start_index, end_index) in enumerate(zip(indices_to_split[:-1],
    ...:  indices_to_split[1:])):
    ...:     if idx ==0:
    ...:         df = pd.read_csv(
    ...:         "test.csv",
    ...:         nrows=end_index - start_index - 1,
    ...:         skiprows=start_index,
    ...: 
    ...:         )
    ...:         cols = df.columns
    ...:     else:
    ...:         df = pd.read_csv(
    ...:             "test.csv",
    ...:              nrows=end_index - start_index,
    ...:              skiprows=start_index,
    ...:              header=None,
    ...:              names=cols,
    ...: 
    ...:          )
    ...:     print(df, end="\n" * 3)
    ...: 
   a
0  1
1  2
2  3


   a
0  4
1  5
2  6


   a
0  7
1  8
2  9
```