# Iterating over a large dataframe and grouping by date

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very large dataframe  that can't all fit into memory at once, the file is ordered by date but each date has a different number of rows. I know I can read the file into chunks via:

```
with pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=chunksize) as reader:
    for df_chunk in reader:
        for g in df_chunk.groupby('date'):
            process(g)
```

However since the number of rows on a given date are different I can't guarantee that I can get all the rows on a given `groupby('date')`. How can I iterate over the large dataframe and group by date to get all rows for each date in the group by?

Comment: you may want to try [Dask](https://examples.dask.org/dataframe.html#).  It supports groupby ops "out of core" for data on disk

Comment: alternatively, you could load the date column only and find row nums of interest where the date changes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas reading large panel CSV efficiently in chunks based on values of a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73271916/pandas-reading-large-panel-csv-efficiently-in-chunks-based-on-values-of-a-column)

Comment: @BeRT2me that actually works great!

Answer (score 1):

Check Below code. Required operations can be performed on extracted **df**

Data used in csv

[image]

```
filename = '/content/dummy_date.csv'

chunksize = 1

filter_column =  'date'

date_list = pd.read_csv(filename, usecols=[filter_column])[filter_column].unique().tolist()

for i in date_list:
  iter_csv = pd.read_csv(filename, iterator=True, chunksize=chunksize)
  df = pd.concat([chunk[chunk['date'] == i] for chunk in iter_csv])
  print(df)
```

Output:

[image]